# Require the www via mod_rewrite - additional conditions needed?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

To rewrite example.com to www.example.com I was told to use the following rules within my root .htaccess file:

```
# Require the www
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap\.xml$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Could you please explain what's the matter with the first five lines here? Are they really needed/recommended? TIA

Answer (score 1):

[.htaccess tricks](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#redirects)  This article will help you to understand  all the tricks about htaccess . Later yourself decide whether you need first five lines

Hope its helpful

Comment: Thanks for the link! I just noticed the 301 redirection does not work if I use RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d. Adding [OR] behind the first condition fixes this. Can you please explain why?